# Too deeply nested at just fourth nesting level using pandoc with markdown?

Tags: latex, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

The following code is not accepted by `pandoc`:

```
1. Code Behaviors
    1. Logging
        1. No "bare" `System.out.println`'s
        1. Logging level can be calibrated by simple change(s) to logging.xml and/or log4j.properties
        1. Errors and exceptions go to appropriate WARN and/or ERROR logging levels
    1. Errors and Exceptions
        1. Almost never "swallowed"
            1. Can only happen for well understood situations
                1. Must be documented clearly in code why they are swallowed
                1. Only a specific exception or error may be swallowed this way
                - In particular can not be done for general Exception.
                - Throwable can never be handled this way
```

Which should look like this:

1. Code Behaviors

   1. Logging

      1. No "bare" `System.out.println`'s
      2. Logging level can be calibrated by simple change(s) to logging.xml and/or log4j.properties
      3. Errors and exceptions go to appropriate WARN and/or ERROR logging levels
   2. Errors and Exceptions

      1. Almost never "swallowed"

         1. Can only happen for well understood situations

            1. Must be documented clearly in code why they are swallowed
            2. Only a specific exception or error may be swallowed this way

               - In particular can not be done for general Exception.
               - Throwable can never be handled this way

Using the command line

```
pandoc --toc  --toc-depth=6 -V fontsize=10pt --pdf-engine xelatex
  -V geometry:"left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm" -o review.pdf review.md
```

We get

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.159         \begin{enumerate}
```

**Update**  I tried to add in additional levels using `enumitem` package to the preamble as suggested here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464459/45938 - but to no effect (same error produced):

```
---
title: My Review
subtitle: My subtitle 
documentclass: extarticle
author: First Last Sept 15, 2019
geometry: "left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{unicode-math}
  - \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
  - \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
  - \usepackage{enumitem}
  - \setlistdepth{20}
  - \renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{20}
  - \setlist[itemize]{label=$\cdot$}
  - \setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textbullet}
  - \setlist[itemize,2]{label=--}
  - \setlist[itemize,3]{label=*}

output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    theme: lumen
    fig_caption: yes

---
```

Comment: yes, this is a LaTeX limitation. btw, you should format your posted input as a code block on SO...

Comment: Can you please add the intermediate .tex file to your question?

Comment: @mb21  Tried to use the `enumitem` package that extends base `lateX` - but still same error

Comment: @samcarter How to generate the intermediate `tex` file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `enumitem` is the correct approach. However, you have to extend both `enumerate` and `itemize` environments:

```
---
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{enumitem}
  - \setlistdepth{20}
  - \renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{20}
  - \renewlist{enumerate}{enumerate}{20}
  - \setlist[itemize]{label=$\cdot$}
  - \setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textbullet}
  - \setlist[itemize,2]{label=--}
  - \setlist[itemize,3]{label=*}
output:
  rmarkdown::pdf_document:
      keep_tex: yes
---

1. Code Behaviors
    1. Logging
        1. No "bare" `System.out.println`'s
        1. Logging level can be calibrated by simple change(s) to logging.xml and/or log4j.properties
        1. Errors and exceptions go to appropriate WARN and/or ERROR logging levels
    1. Errors and Exceptions
        1. Almost never "swallowed"
            1. Can only happen for well understood situations
                1. Must be documented clearly in code why they are swallowed
                1. Only a specific exception or error may be swallowed this way
                    - In particular can not be done for general Exception.
                    - Throwable can never be handled this way
```

Output:

[image]

Note: The `output.rmakrdown::pdf_document.keep_tex` flag means that the intermediate `tex` file is retained.

Comment: **Fantastic!!**  I use _pandoc_ / _teX_ / _pdf_ for _everything_ so this is so important.  For other readers - the specific added code for fixing added here is `- \renewlist{enumerate}{enumerate}{20}`